# MySQL: Order by field size/length

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Here is a table structure (e.g. test):

| Field Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | BIGINT (20) |
| title | varchar(25) |
| Description | Text |

A query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY description DESC;
```

But I would like to order by the **field size/length** of the field description.

The field type will be TEXT or BLOB.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY LENGTH(description) DESC;
```

The [`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function gives the length of string in bytes. If you want to count (multi-byte) characters, use the [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function instead:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(description) DESC;
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer: if the type is BLOB, you can use `OCTET_LENGTH(column_name)`.

Comment: @mastazi according to MySQL documentation: OCTET_LENGTH() is a synonym for LENGTH().

Comment: 'CHAR_LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name. I am facing this error

Answer (score 8):

For those using MS SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY LEN(field)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(description);
```

Comment: 'CHAR_LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name. I am facing this error