# SQL / MySQL - Order By Length of Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL, is there a way to order my results by the length (characters) of a column?

For example:

```
myColumn
________________
lor
lorem
lorem ip
lorem ips
lorem ipsum
```

I would like to order my results by the smallest column length first, "lor", and ending in the largest column length, "lorem ipsum". This should include column lengths of 0 too.

Any suggestions gratefully received...

Comment: asked already see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572118/mysql-order-by-field-size-length

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use **[`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)** function:

```
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH( column )
```

Notice that `CHAR_LENGTH()` works for Unicode strings as well, where `LENGTH()` is OK for Latin but may give unexpected results with Unicode:

> CHAR_LENGTH(str)
>
> Returns the length of the string str, measured in characters. A multi-byte character counts as a single character. This means that for a string containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

Comment: CHAR______________LENGTH

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY LENGTH(my_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) operator.

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(myColumn)
```