# ORDER BY in MySql based on LIKE condition

Tags: mysql

I am facing difficulty in sorting the result based on field in mysql. Say for example I am searching the word "Terms" then I should get the results which starts with 'Terms' first and then 'Terms and' as next and then 'Terms and conditions' and so on.

Any one please help out who to fetch the search result based on my requirements in efficient manner using mysql query.

Comment: Did you want to sort based on the length of the string? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572118/mysql-order-by-field-size-length

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE "Terms%" ORDER BY your_column;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for fulltext search. Below a very simple example

```
SELECT id,name MATCH (name) AGAINST ('string' > 'string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('string' > 'string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The advantage of this is that you can control the value of words. This is very basic, you can 'up' some matches or words (or 'down' them)
In my example an exact match (`'string'`) would get a higher score than the string with something attached (`'string*'`). The following line is even one step broader:

```
'string' > 'string*' > '*string*'
```

[This documentation about fulltextsearch](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) explains allot. It's a long read, but worth it and complete.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the storage engine and mysql version you probably can use the full text search capabilities of MySQL. For example:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (your_column) AGAINST ('Terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM your_table 
WHERE MATCH (your_column) AGAINST ('Terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance
```

You can find more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Or if you don't want FTS another possible solution where ordering is strictly based on the length (difference) of the strings.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE "Terms%" ORDER BY ABS(LENGTH(your_column) - LENGTH('Terms'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fulltext index if you search for *prefix* string!

Using `LIKE "Term%"` the optimizer will be able to use a potential index on `your_column`:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
   WHERE your_column LIKE "Terms%" 
   ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(your_column),your_column
```

Note the `ORDER BY` clause: it first sorts by string length, and only use alphabetcal order to sort strings of equal length.

And please, use [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)  and not [`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) as the first count the number of characters, whereas the later count number of bytes. Using a *variable* length encoding such as utf8, this would made a difference.