# Select All states having smallest name in each country. Show respective country name as well

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables as below

- **country**
  Field like(id*,code,name)
- ***state***
  Field Like(id,name,country_id)

how can i List all states having smallest name in each country. Show respective country name as well.

here is what i am trying, where and how i use group by ?

Query :

```
SELECT c.name,
       s.name,
       char_length(s.name)
FROM state s
JOIN country c ON s.country_id = c.id
ORDER BY char_length(s.name)
```

Comment: A sliiiight sense of an interview question.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572118/mysql-order-by-field-size-length

Answer (score 0):

I'm more used to Sql Server than MySql but this works I think. There is a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22a928/21) too.

```
SELECT c.NAME as country_name
    ,s.state_name
    ,s.state_name_length
FROM country c
JOIN (
    SELECT sl.NAME state_name
        ,char_length(sl.NAME) state_name_length
        ,sl.country_id 
    FROM STATE sl
    WHERE char_length(sl.NAME) = (
            SELECT min(char_length(sm.NAME))
            FROM state sm
            WHERE sm.country_id = sl.country_id
            )
    ) s ON c.id = s.country_id
ORDER BY s.state_name_length
```