# How to find the biggest word (in terms of LENGTH) in a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a few `mudiumtext` datatype columns. Now I need to find the **longest word in each row**, in terms of word LENGTH. Like below.

The text column is for storing product description (like a paragraph in general understanding). So the column has multiple words. And I need to find what is the longest word in the column.

I tried with union all, but word count in rows is dynamic.

```
select sum(len) from (
SELECT LENGTH(description) - LENGTH(REPLACE(description, ' ', '')) + 1 as len
FROM test.city
union all
SELECT LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) + 1 as len
FROM test.city
) as tablen;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Those subtracts calculate the _number of words_, not the _longest word_.  Which did you want?  (And it has flaws with two spaces together, punctuation, etc.  But it might be close enough for your purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot see your data set, but maybe code below helps you.

Below SQL - select first "ascending" smallest station.city and show character count in selected word/s

```
SELECT STATION.CITY, LENGTH(STATION.CITY) 
FROM STATION 
WHERE
LENGTH(STATION.CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(STATION.CITY)) FROM STATION) 
ORDER BY STATION.CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Below SQL - select first "ascending" biggest station.city and show character count in selected word/s

```
SELECT STATION.CITY, LENGTH(STATION.CITY)
FROM STATION 
WHERE
LENGTH(STATION.CITY) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(STATION.CITY)) FROM STATION) 
ORDER BY STATION.CITY ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Your Output will be (stdout)

```
Amo 3
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it by sorting the list according to the length of the words and then pick up the first element:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And for calculating the length of the row you can use something like

```
SELECT *,  CHAR_LENGTH(name) + CHAR_LENGTH(description) as len FROM TEST ORDER BY len DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Hope that will solve your problem if I correctly understood it

Comment: And try it with CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572118/mysql-order-by-field-size-length

Comment: `TOP 1` is not a MySQL construct.  The `LENGTH` calculations seem to be unrelated to the Question.  In some sense `CHAR_LENGTH` is more appropriate, but when replacing `' '`, it has zero impact on the result.